# Cannot navigate to package body because this spec has no body

Tags: oracle, package, toad

I faced with the problem at Toad 11.6.1 I cannot open package body of Oracle database on Toad 11.6. So when I click button **Toggle Spec/Body** The following info was showing:

**Cannot navigate to package body because this spec has no body**

But when I connect to the same DB with with the same username with TOAD 10.1.1 everything is ok. It means that I have access to see the package and it's body. I have no idea what maybe the problem.

Comment: This belongs on a Toad support site/bug tracker.

Comment: Are you sure that this is BUG?

Comment: You say it yourself. Works in vX.Y, doesn't work in vA.B.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the package isn't owned by the user you're connecting as?

If so, TOAD has an option to use DBA views which is NOT checked by default. Is it checked in your 11.6 version? if not, then unless you have DEBUG privilege on the package, you won't see the body.

Comment: on Toad version 10 everything is ok. I think this is version problem.

Comment: @RovshanMusayev so is the DBA view option checked in your 11.6 version then? if so raise a ticket with the TOAD support guys.